# Looping through Datagrid for checked Checkboxs to create a list

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, foreach

I have a Silverlight DataGrid, not an asp Gridview, that gets populated just fine. I have added a checkbox column for the user to select which items they want to download. My goal is to create a 'cart' where the user can select their items, then click a button to add them. Then they will go to a checkout page etc..

My problem so far is that I am having trouble checking to see if the user checked a check box or not. My foreach loops through fine I think, but I get a 'nullreferenceexception' in the bool IsChecked line. During a breakpoint, none of the values came back as null that I saw but it obviously isnt working the way I hoped.

```
foreach (var row in gridResults.ItemsSource)
        {
            bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)gridResults.Columns[8].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;

            if (IsChecked)
            {
                List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();
                string fileName = (gridResults.SelectedItem as JobSearchResult).FileName;
                lstFile.Add(fileName);
            }
        }
```

Through the filename, I can find the files on the server for them to download, but How can i check if they checked the ones they wanted or not?

Comment: Have you already debugged through the "IsChecked line" to verify what is the exactly part is throwing the exception?

Comment: It hits the error there and then straight to my unhandled exception in app.xaml.cs, which just brings up a broken debugger. (Always says you are already debugging this, exiting...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing precisely how you are populating your datagrid, it is difficult to tell you what the exact cause of your issue is.  But I will tell you how I would handle this situation.

Create an ObservableCollection of your object type.  Set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to the ObservableCollection.  Then, in the data grid row, create a binding for the IsChecked property of the checkbox to some public boolean value on your object (perhaps call that IsSelected).  Make sure to set the binding mode to TwoWay.

Then, all you have to do is use a linq query on the ObservableCollection.  Remember that Silverlight is a presentation layer, and you should not rely upon it at all to perform business logic.

Comment: It is retrieving the data through a linq query which calls a class I made to talk to a stored procedure in the db. It is heavily based on which parameters are input to get the results. Not positive, but I think reassigning the itemsource will cause this to not function correctly (or its current way)

Comment: Is this thing constantly refreshing?  If so, how is the datagrid not getting refreshed every time?  Why can't you just dump the query results into the ObservableCollection?

Comment: Ok, I got that part to work. It passes the check and only adds the checked options to the list. However it only adds the latest one I 'selected' and if a scroll up and down on the datagrid, it erases everything the is also not the one i last 'selected'

Comment: Go ahead and post your XAML.  I think the problem is that your databinding is not properly working.

Comment: Ya it is a databinding issue, I ended up creating a partial class to tell my model that there was an bool field in the db table without creating one. I think I have it, thanks for your help.